# Como receber o retorno de um texto selecionado dentro no windows?

Tags: java, windows

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma `classe no java`, com algum método que me possibilite receber aqueles trechos de texto que selecionamos com o curso de texto em algum documento qualquer dentro do `Windows`(seja um texto de um `PDF`,`Word` ou algum `página web`).

A razão pela qual estou querendo essa funcionalidade, é que irei desenvolver um programa que usa esse trecho de texto adquirido através da seleção,como entrada para que algum  servidor de dicionário me retorne o significado da palavra.

Answer (score 0):

Não, não existem classes para esta funcionalidade dentro da Plataforma Java SE ou Java EE. O que não significa que você não possa contruir essa funcionalidade utilizando Java, é perfeitamente possível. Você vai precisar escrever código nativo. Isto vai realmente prender seu código mais ao Sistema Operacional, no seu caso Windows.

Para isso Java prove o que nós chamamos de ***JNI***

**Java Native Interface**

Confira documentação aqui: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

leia cuidadosamente este outro tutorial

http://blog.caelum.com.br/escrevendo-metodos-nativos-em-java-com-jni-e-jna/

Por último, mas não menos importante, encontrei esse código feito para alguém queria fazer algo mito semelhante ao que você quer fazer:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Foo implements ClipboardOwner {
    public interface CustomUser32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        CustomUser32 INSTANCE = (CustomUser32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", CustomUser32.class);
        HWND GetForegroundWindow();
        void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
    }

    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {
        // dummy: needed for `ClipboardOwner`
    }

    void controlC(CustomUser32 customUser32) {
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x11 /* VK_CONTROL*/, (byte) 0, 0, 0);
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x43 /* 'C' */, (byte) 0, 0, 0);
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x43 /* 'C' */, (byte) 0, 2 /* KEYEVENTF_KEYUP */, 0);
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x11 /* VK_CONTROL*/, (byte) 0, 2 /* KEYEVENTF_KEYUP */, 0);// 'Left Control Up
    }

    String getClipboardText() throws Exception {
        return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }

    void setClipboardText(String data) throws Exception {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(data), this);
    }

    String getSelectedText(User32 user32, CustomUser32 customUser32) throws Exception {
        HWND hwnd = customUser32.GetForegroundWindow();
        char[] windowText = new char[512];
        user32.GetWindowText(hwnd, windowText, 512);
        String windowTitle = Native.toString(windowText);
        System.out.println("Will take selected text from the following window: [" + windowTitle + "]");
        String before = getClipboardText();
        controlC(customUser32); // emulate Ctrl C
        Thread.sleep(100); // give it some time
        String text = getClipboardText();
        System.out.println("Currently in clipboard: " + text);
        // restore what was previously in the clipboard
        setClipboardText(before);
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Thread.sleep(2000); // take some time for you to select something anywhere
        System.out.println(foo.getSelectedText(User32.INSTANCE, CustomUser32.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

Quando você rodar, vc terá dois segundos para selecionar texto em qualquer aplicação e então vai printar essas strings.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839780/monitor-text-that-is-highlighted

Comment: Filipe,
Será uma motivação a mais implementar essas funcionalidades extras.
Sou muito grato pela sua ajuda.É pena ainda não posso votar ,se não você teria meu voto garantido!!
Abraços